# Pass io.BytesIO object to gzip.GzipFile and write to GzipFile

Tags: python-3.x, gzip, bytesio

I basically want to do exactly whats in the documentation of `gzip.GzipFile`:

> Calling a GzipFile object’s close() method does not close fileobj, since you might wish to append more material after the compressed data. This also allows you to pass a io.BytesIO object opened for writing as fileobj, and retrieve the resulting memory buffer using the io.BytesIO object’s getvalue() method.

With a normal file object it works as expected.

```
>>> import gzip
>>> fileobj = open("test", "wb")
>>> fileobj.writable()
True
>>> gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fileobj)
>>> gzipfile.writable()
True
```

But I can't manage to get a writable `gzip.GzipFile` object when passing a `io.BytesIO` object.

```
>>> import io
>>> bytesbuffer = io.BytesIO()
>>> bytesbuffer.writable()
True
>>> gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=bytesbuffer)
>>> gzipfile.writable()
False
```

Do I have to open the `io.BytesIO` explicit for writing, and how would I do so? Or is there a difference between a file object returned by `open(filename, "wb")` and a object returned by `io.BytesIO()`  I didn't think of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need to explicitly set the `GzipFile` mode to `'w'`; it would otherwise try and take the mode from the file object, but a `BytesIO` object has no `.mode` attribute:

```
>>> import io
>>> io.BytesIO().mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

Just specify the mode explicitly:

```
gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fileobj, mode='w')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(), mode='w').writable()
True
```

In principle a `BytesIO` object is opened in `'w+b'` mode, but `GzipFile` would only look at the first character of a file mode.