# Reading contents of a gzip file from a AWS S3 using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

Below is the code I am using to read gz file

```
import json
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

def lambda_handler(event, context):
try:
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 key='test.gz'
 obj = s3.Object('athenaamit',key)
 n = obj.get()['Body'].read()
 #print(n)
 gzip = BytesIO(n)
 gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzip)
 content = gzipfile.read()
 print(content)
 return 'dddd'
```

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e
But I am gettting below error

```
 "errorMessage": "'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'GzipFile'",
 "stackTrace": [
 "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",
"  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzip)\n"
```

python version -3.7

I also tried to implement below suggestion
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794837/pass-io-bytesio-object-to-gzip- 
   gzipfile-and-write-to-gzipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794837/pass-io-bytesio-object-to-gzip-gzipfile-and-write-to-gzipfile)

but its also not working for me,
kindly suggest how I can read content of file

Comment: You have a conflict in your naming conventions.  Change the variable name assignment for `gzip = BytesIO(n)` to a different variable name.  As written you are overwriting the functionality of the `gzip` module by naming a variable `gzip` in your code.

Comment: @vealkind thanks that is a silly mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading contents of a gzip file from a AWS S3 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161006/reading-contents-of-a-gzip-file-from-a-aws-s3-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

Finishing this into a proper answer. The working code would be:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('my-bucket-name','path/to/file.gz')
buf = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) # reads whole gz file into memory
for line in gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf):
    # do something with line
```

I was a bit worried about memory footprint, but it seems that only the gz file is kept in memory (line 3 above). And then only every single line in unzipped form in the `for line` loop.

With a gz file of `38M` I had a memory footprint of `47M` (in virtual memory, `VIRT` in htop). The unzipped file was `308M`.